# An error in browser: React is not defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

I try to run my React framework with Asp.net MVC in visual studio 2015. In scripts folder, I add new folder where I add `package.json`, `webpack config` and `tsconfig`. In another folder I add `app.js` file and there I want to import other components and display something on the page. I can compile webpack withour any error but when I open my `/Home/Index` site nothing is displayed. In developer tools I have only information

```
 React is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:85)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.module.exports (bundle.js:73)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at bundle.js:63
    at bundle.js:66
```

Of course I try to find sometihng information but nothing help. Before I had `tsx` extension for my `app.js` but I read that is not recommended. Before I share my app.js file. Of course I include file with `dist.js`.

```
import { React } from "react";

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello</h1>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: the correct is `import React from "react";`

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: are you run `webpack` to build agian ?

Comment: Of course. I think if it is incorrect webpack will crush.